# Usage of OmniFaces Param.validatorAttributes

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I try to use the OmniFaces [@Param](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Param) annotation to inject a request parameter.
I also make use of its `validatorClasses` attribute to validate the parameter. Eventually this used validator needs a special attribute to function and I want to pass the value by setting the `validatorAttributes` attribute. Unfortunately I don't know how. The [documentation](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/2.7/org/omnifaces/cdi/Param.html#validatorAttributes--) provides a description but I just don't get it right.

Can someone help please?

Here's some code:

```
    @Inject
    @Param(
            name = "the_param_name",
            validatorClasses = MyFreshValidator.class,
            validatorAttributes = ?
    )
    private MyFreshClass instance;
```

It would be ideal to give another object of the same class to the validator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's indeed slightly hidden in the [showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Param). If you open the `CdiParamBean` tab of the "Demo source code" section, then you'll find the managed bean's source code with below examples:

```
// Like <f:viewParam name="text2" value="#{bean.text2}" validatorMessage="..."><f:validateLength minimum="3">
@Inject @Param(
    validatorClasses = LengthValidator.class,
    validatorAttributes = @Attribute(name="minimum", value="3"),
    validatorMessage = "{1}: Value is too too small! Please enter a minimum of 3 characters.")
private String text2;
```

```
// Like <f:viewParam name="date" value="#{bean.date}" converterMessage="..."><f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyyMMdd">
@Inject @Param(
    converterClass = DateTimeConverter.class,
    converterAttributes = { @Attribute(name="pattern", value="yyyyMMdd") },
    converterMessage="{1}: \"{0}\" is not the date format we had in mind! Please use the format yyyyMMdd.")
private Date date;
```

Here, the `@Attribute` is the `org.omnifaces.cdi.param.Attribute`.

I'll look at [improving](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/524) the documentation in a future version.

Comment: I guess it's not possible to pass a non-constant value for `value` (e.g. a field of the same class), right?

Comment: The `value` supports EL. So you could use e.g. `value="#{bean.property}"`.